# How to send ajax get request in nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, ui-automation, nightwatch.js, ajax-request

I am working in UI automation testing project i need to send a ajax request to my server but in Nighwatch.js some functions of vanilla javascript and JQuery functions are not acceptable,

so if anyone has any experience to send Ajax get request to server in nightwatch.js environment then please give me some info/suggestions.

Comment: Maybe use xhr? https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: i tried code from given url but i am getting following error.

"XMLHttpRequest is not defined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long research i found request.js a node module, I have resolved my issue by installing ["request" node module](https://github.com/request/request). After installing i am able to perform "GET" and "POST" requests to my servers within **Nightwatch** environment. I am writing piece of code which working like a charm.

```
/* jshint expr: true */
module.exports = {
'@tags' : ['book'],
beforeEach : function (client) {

},
after : function (client) {
    client.end();
},
wGroup: {
    book_url: "https://example.myApi.mycompany.in"
},

userSettings: Array(),

"Get all settings": function (client, done) {
    var widget = this.wGroup;
    client.getreq( widget.book_url + "/api/store", widget, function (response) {
        client.assert.equal(response.statusCode, 200, "201 Created");
        var objects = response.body.objects;
        client.userSettings = objects;
        console.log( 'Found number of settings: ' + client.userSettings.length );
        client.end();
    });
},

"Remove settings": function (client, done) {
    var widget  = this.wGroup;
    var objects = client.userSettings;
    for( i=0; i<objects.length; i++ ) {
        var obj = objects[i];
        console.log('Removing user settings id ' + obj.id );
        client.deletereq( widget.book_url: l + "/api/store" + obj.id, widget, function (resp) {
            client.assert.equal(resp.statusCode, 204, "204 Created");
            client.end();
        });
     }
   },
};
```